# Can you overload the match operator?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, structural-pattern-matching

There are many operators in python that can be overloaded (like `+`). But going through the docs for python 3.10 and [PEP 622](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/), I was wondering whether the same can be done for the `match` operator (e.g. to simplify an object's representation) - or would this be done through the `__match_args__` attribute?

Comment: What is a match operator?

Comment: I figure, it is actually called [match statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#the-match-statement). Which probably means, that it cannot be overloaded, because it is no operator, but a statement. Good enough for me :)

Comment: True that. With respect to what you ask, I noted what it says in [The Match Protocol](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#the-match-protocol) section — "Classes requiring different matching semantics (such as duck-typing) can do so by defining `__instancecheck__` (a pre-existing metaclass hook) or by using `typing.Protocol`."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you overload the match operator?

The short answer is **No**.

The logic for Structural Pattern Matching is hardwired into the [grammar of the language](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html).  The only method hook is [`__match_args__`](https://Here%20a%20class%20was%20chosen%20because%20it%20is%20simple%20and%20doesn%27t%20have%20any%20of%20the%20complexity%20associated%20with%20Enum.%20%20Additionally,%20the%20class%20namespace%20works%20with%20descriptors%20which%20were%20needed%20for%20the%20more%20advance%20solution.) which is only used to give field names for positional arguments in the [class pattern](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#class-patterns).